# Sort jekyll posts by hash value?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Using Jekyll 3.1.1. Given posts with headers containing:

```
categories: works
sitemap:
  priority: 0.8
  chagefreq: yearly
```

I don't seem to be able to do this...

```
{% assign prioritized = site.categories.works | sort: 'page.sitemap.priority' | reverse %}
{% for work in prioritized %}...{% endfor %}
```

A `| sort: 'priority'` would work just fine, if I instead
defined a single variable.

```
priority: 0.8
```

but I'd rather my sitemap priority double for this purpose. DRY, ya know?
Is something like this possible?

Comment: Not possible as you can see here https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3351#issuecomment-71409538

Comment: Ah, thanks @DavidJacquel, I'll keep an eye on liquid issue #604 and future jekyll updates. Glad a nested_sort is being considered.

Comment: Yes, liquid will (maybe) introduce it, but as Jekyll is overriding the liquid sort method, I'm afraid it will not appear on Jekyll side of the force.